# Dirac Delta Distribution and non-compactly supported test function

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

I would like to know if there is any problem with defining the following expression:
$$
I = \int_0^\infty g(t) \delta(f(t))\mathrm{d}t 
$$
where $0<\lim\limits_{t\to\infty} g(t) =L<\infty$ and $f(t)>0$ for all $t\in[0,\infty)$ but $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty} f(t) =0$, such that

$$I = \lim\limits_{t\to\infty} g(t) = L$$
For example, is the following correct?
$$
\int_0^\infty \underbrace{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{t}}}_{=g(t)} \text{ }\delta\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)\mathrm{d}t = \lim\limits_{t\to\infty} g(t) = 1
$$

I was wondering if this is well-defined because one usually uses compactly supported test functions, but I do not have a thorough training on distributions yet.

Comment: Your $g$ does not inherently present any particular difficulty; one can apply any distribution with compact support inside $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{ 0 \}$ to it, and $\delta$ has compact support. (Note "inside" $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{ 0 \}$, the support of the distribution must not contain zero). Your composition is a problem, however: if $\delta(1/t)$ is to make sense, then it must be the zero distribution, since $1/t$ is never zero. The fact that $1/t \to 0$ at infinity doesn't help you here at all, again because distributions are defined by their action on smooth compactly supported functions.

Comment: To clarify that last remark, sometimes distributions can be extended to a larger domain than $C^\infty_c$. This happens when the distribution is continuous with respect to a coarser topology on $C^\infty_c$ than the usual one. (For instance, it might be continuous with respect to the topology of uniform convergence on compact subsets.) So we can often continuously extend it to the closure of $C^\infty_c$ in whatever coarser topology. But the continuous extension will always be uniquely determined by the behavior on $C^\infty_c$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Ian, that was a very helpful explanation . I have resorted to using a different notation for my purposes that circumvents the use of the Dirac Delta.